# LogCat & Console stopped working with Eclipse Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, console

The Console and LogCat printouts stopped working in Eclipse with the Android Emulator.

I'm getting the following Exception in the Console

> [2011-11-10 11:04:58 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.]device not found
>       com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
>           at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
>           at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
>           at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:319)
>           at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:100)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Usually when the emulator is loading or updating an apk there's a printout in the Console telling the status. Now the Console is just blank.

I made sure the emulator is selected in the DDMS Tab.

I tried deleting and recreating the emulator in the AVD Manager. I restarted eclipse and the computer. I also updated all of the android and eclipse software in hope that the problem may get fixed. But, to no avail.

It may be related to a problem I had in my code yesterday. There was an unending loop in my code, so I had to stop the emulator mid code running.

Comment: do you have spaces in your in the path where android sdk is installed? i.e. does your path look like - C:\Program Files (x86)\android\android-sdk?

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar error and it was driving me crazy. I just got it to work by doing the following steps:

> 1. In a shell or command prompt run: adb kill-server
> 2. Unplug the USB cable from the device and plug it back in.
> 3. Open the devices view (Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Devices)
> 4. Click on the device on the android devices view.

I tested this for the emulator and it works if you relaunch the emulator instead of step 2.

Another way I got it to work was to restart Eclipse. But that's not usually ideal.

Note: Logcat would stop working any time I disconnected the usb cable from my android device (similar to killing an emulator).

I recognize this might not fix your initial issue, but it might help others who stumble on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, install the SDK even three times as TT, but the solution is to go to the folder android-sdk-windows, then platform-tools, and double click adb and ready!

Answer (score 1):

Clean project with Project/Clean...

Answer (score 1):

deleting the emulator and creating a new one did the job for me.
Even in my case a faulty code or a secret infinite loop, i think is the problem. i tried out something and logcat failed to boot up since then.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have 2 instances of Eclipse running (I did). 
(On Windows) Exit eclipse then check with the Task Manager if there is another eclipse.
End it as well as any image name "adb".